# Specific user access to branches in one repository of GitHub

Tags: github, repository, branch, multiple-users

There are numbers of users and specific user has to get dev branch write access and need not have write access to prod.
How to give user specific access through branches in one repository of GitHub
Example: repo1 of branches dev QA uat prod
User1 should have access to dev write but not to prod.
Only specific users for reviewer as pr requests for specific branches.